# SQL Insert new line

Tags: sql

I have a problem I don't know how to add a new line to a table. I just wish to add one more line with the same ID_Group but with different ID_item.
I have a column named ID_group with id from 1 to 230 and each ID_group have 7 lines (query below). Now i need to add a 8th line to each ID_group because there's a new id_item that is 7 (logically) This query only shows what I'm talking about

```
id_group    id_item
   9        0
   9        1
   9        2
   9        3
   9        4
   9        5
   9        6
  10        0
  10        1
  10        2
  10        3
  10        4
  10        5
  10        6
  11        0
  11        1
  11        2
  11        3
  11        4
  11        5
  11        6
  13        0
  13        1
  13        2
  13        3
  13        4
  13        5
  13        6
```

Can you help me?

One more thing. I'm new to SQL and development so sorry for any stupid question.

Comment: Sorry, where is the query?

Comment: Search on Google to learn basic of SQL.

Comment: can you show us the sql query as it stands?

Comment: http://beginner-sql-tutorial.com/sql-insert-statement.htm

Comment: lookup SQL INSERT command

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming T-SQL and that I understand you're trying to add an id_item 7 for each existing id_group, this should do it:

```
INSERT INTO [tablename] (id_group,id_item)
SELECT DISTINCT id_group,7
FROM [tablename];
```

You'll have to substitute the actual table name for `[tablename]`.

Comment: what if i had another column with values that are also the same for each id_group. I can't user the distinct for both columns?

Comment: @Hugo You could add that column to the INSERT INTO and the SELECT DISTINCT if you're OK with the new records having the same id_dispenser, so you'd have INSERT INTO [tablename] (id_group,id_dispenser,id_item)
SELECT DISTINCT id_group,id_dispenser,7
FROM [tablename];

Answer (score 2):

```
Insert MyTable (Id_group, ID_Item)
select distinct Id_group,7 from MyTable
```

Comment: I think you mean `Insert into`.

Comment: @Kaf into is entirely optional and adds nothing